# PowerShell module is loaded but no cmdlets available

Tags: powershell

I have made a PowerShell module which is stored on a network share. In the module I have a function to connect to Exchange Online.

When I import the module from the network share and use the function to connect to Exchange Online the module is loaded (at least according to the verbose output):

```
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_22gpyzrn.tf1\tmp_22gpyzrn.tf1.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading 'FormatsToProcess' from path
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_22gpyzrn.tf1\tmp_22gpyzrn.tf1.format.ps1xml'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_22gpyzrn.tf1\tmp_22gpyzrn.tf1.psm1'.
```

Full verbose output: https://pastebin.com/5tZhVPyj

However, no cmdlets from Exchange Online e.g. Get-Mailbox are available. When I run Get-Module I cannot see that the module has been loaded. If I go the the Temp folder I can see that the module has in fact been downloaded. I can even load the module by using

```
Import-Module 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_22gpyzrn.tf1'
```

If I copy my function to the PowerShell console and execute the code and run the function the module from Exchange Online will be loaded correctly. I am able to see it listed when using Get-Module and cmdlets such as Get-Mailbox are available.

Verbose output: https://pastebin.com/JNjyYguQ

Other functions from the same module works fine, but something odd is happening when I'm connecting to Exchange Online (and Security and Compliance as well).

Is there a security setting or similar I am overlooking?

Comment: Can you try $env:psmodulepath = $env:psmodulepath +";\\ServerShare\Folder\modules"; Import-Module ModuleName

Comment: Use `Get-Module` to see that the module loaded. Use `Get-Command -Module` to see the commands made available from the module.

Comment: The thing is that the module appears loaded, but it isn't: https://pastebin.com/wTxASYrs